# express session and connect redis error on saving session redis store (TypeError: this.client.set is not a function)

Tags: node.js, express, redis, express-session, connect-redis

I am trying to implement express-session and connect-redis to manage session for my node application.

I already follow instructions on how to apply the express-session with connect-redis

app.js

```
import express from "express";
import http from "http";
import session from "express-session";
import connectRedis from "connect-redis";

const app = express();
const StoreRedis = connectRedis(session);

sessionConfig.setStorage(new StoreRedis({ client: redisService() }));


app.use(session(sessionConfig.getConfig()));

const server =
    appConfig.SECURE == true
      ? https.createServer({}, app)
      : http.createServer(app);

app.use("/", router);

  server.listen(appConfig.GAME_SERVICE_PORT, appConfig.SERVER_HOST, () => {
    const protocol = appConfig.SECURE == true ? "https" : "http";
    console.log(
      `Server started ${protocol}://${appConfig.SERVER_HOST}:${appConfig.GAME_SERVICE_PORT}`
    );
  });
```

redis-service.js

```
import { createClient } from "redis";
export default async () => {
  // redis[s]://[[username][:password]@][host][:port][/db-number]
  const redisClient = createClient({
    // url: `redis://${REDIS_USERNAME}:@${REDIS_PASSWORD}${REDIS_HOST}:${REDIS_PORT}`,
    legacyMode: true,
  });

  redisClient.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Could not establish a connection with redis. " + err);
  });
  redisClient.on("connect", function (err) {
    console.log("Connected to redis successfully");
  });

  await redisClient.connect();

  return redisClient;
};
```

route.js

```
    export default (request, response, next) => {
  request.session.key = "aaaaa";
  response.render("game", {
    title: "title of the game",
  });
};
```

[image: SERVER LOG]

WHEN I TRIED TO ACCESS THE URL FOR THE ROUTE GIVE ME THIS ERROR
[image: ERROR LOG]

WHEN I TRY TO SAVE DATA TO THE REDIS IT CAN SAVE DATA

```
await redisClient.set("input", "value");
```

MY PROBLEM IS ON THE REDIS STORE.

package.json node version 16.16.0

[image]

THANKS FOR THE HELP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redisService()` returns `Promise<RedisClient>`, but `StoreRedis` expected `client` to be `RedisClient`.

I'm pretty sure that if you can use `import` you can use `top-level-await` as well, so I'll use it in the solution below:

```js
// `redis-service.js`
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const client = createClient({
  // ...
  legacyMode: true
});

client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Could not establish a connection with redis', err));
client.on('connect', () => console.log('Connected to redis successfully'));

await client.connect();

export default client;

// `app.js`
// ...
import redisClient from './redis-service.js';
// ...
sessionConfig.setStorage(new StoreRedis({ client: redisClient }));
// ...
```

Comment: yes, already solved the problem, after series trying. thank you anyway for your feedback